# Why is my aloe turning brown?

Tags: plant-care

My aloe plant has been turning brown for several months. I can’t tell if I’ve been overwatering or underwatering it.
[image: aloe plant]

Comment: Are the leaves turning mushy , or are they drying out? Usually, Mushy = too **much** water; and Dry = too **little** water. But I’d like to know how much you water it and how often.

Comment: I water it about once a week. The leaves are definitely dry and not mushy. I reported it recently, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: It's placed by a window so it probably receives a good amount of light. Aloe turns brown when too much light falls on it. Just place it in a spot with very less light and it should turn back green in a matter of 2-3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume that when you say you "reported it" you mean you repotted it? If thats the case, plants take time to recover from being disturbed. How long has it been since you repotted it?

I doubt this is too much exposure to sun. In fact it appears to have been grown in low light conditions for quite some time. Overexposure would show up as dull red leaves,

Plants (not just Aloe) will abandon older, less efficient leaves when stressed. Especially when they are stressed by repotting. The newest growth on your plant looks healthy and green. Aloe leaves are not immortal, there is a cycle, the end of which is dehydration and death of the leaf. Generally the oldest leaves die first.

Many Aloes are generally not neat and organized growers. The more sun exposure they get, the more compact the plant will be. This has nothing to do with general health, it's what they do to survive; they grow towards the light. That can make long "stems" like yours. You can see the tip of your plant turning to the window, trying to get light.

I recommend watering sparingly for a few weeks, and cut off any obviously dead parts. I think your plant is recovering from being repotted and the growth has been stretched by a lack of sunlight. None of this is bad in my opinion.

If you want to grow nice tight Aloe rosettes you'll need to change the growing conditions to something with much more sunlight, among other things. That isn't always possible, depending on where you live, so you get somewhat atypical aloe growth.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I repotted about a month ago and the plant has been through a lot in the last couple of months (a move). I don’t mind if it looks neat, I’d just like it to stay alive!